# cropper does not displaying second image on the canvas

Tags: jquery, html

I have issue for jquery cropper.
For the second loaded image from input type="file" selected image does not display on the canvas.

Following methods does not solve my problem.

1. $().cropper("destroy");
2. $().cropper("replace");

First loaded image has no problem. Issue has just  second loaded image.

All parts is work without problem on my side except second loaded image does not place on the canvas.

Where is my issue?

I can not fix it myself.

also here for alternate example: https://jsfiddle.net/dgnzcn/2t46mzod/14/

```js
    $("#dosya").on("change", function(e) {
       
      var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
          file = this.files[0],                   
          image = new Image();
          image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);    
          image.onload = function(e) {
            var image = document.getElementById('image'),
            button = document.getElementById('kaydet');
        $('#image').attr('src',  _URL.createObjectURL(file));
        $('#image').show();
        $('#kaydet').show();
        var cropper = new Cropper(image, {

            viewMode: 1,

          ready: function () {
     
            croppable = true;
            button.onclick = function () {
              var croppedCanvas;
              var roundedCanvas;
              var roundedImage;
                
              if (!croppable) {
                return;
              }
        
              croppedCanvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
              cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                fillColor: '#fff',
                imageSmoothingEnabled: true,
                imageSmoothingQuality: 'high',
              });
       
              roundedCanvas = getRoundedCanvas(croppedCanvas);
  
              roundedImage = document.createElement('img');
              roundedImage.src = roundedCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.5);
              base64Gorsel.innerHTML = '';
              base64Gorsel.appendChild(roundedImage);
              $("input[name='base64dosya']").val(base64Gorsel.innerHTML);   

            }
                       

          }
            
        });
      }
    });
```

```html
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/css/main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/css/cropper.css">
     
    <img class="img-fluid" id="image">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-10 p-2">
                    <form onsubmit="return false;" id="SayfaYukleForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <h5 class="text-center text-info">Yeni ekleme</h5>                      
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file form-control-file-sm" id="dosya" required accept="image/*">

<span style="" name="base64" id="base64Gorsel"></span>

 <input type="hidden" name="base64dosya"></div>                    
   
<div class="form-group text-right">

<button id="kaydet" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Kaydet</button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/js/cropper.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/js/main.js"></script>
```